# Confusion with recv() in C, is there an underlying input buffer? Where is data coming from?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, recv

I'm just learning socket/network programming in C, and have run into a situation where the `recv()` function is resulting in some unexpected behaviour (unexpected to me at least).

I have a server program with a socket set up, and a call to `recv()` like so:

```
bytes_received = recv(connected, recv_data, 5, 0);
```

`recv_data` is a 5 byte buffer.

My client program uses `send()` to send data, its sending buffer is 1024 bytes, though  since it is reading from standard input, I've only been giving it between 1-10 bytes during this experiment (characters).

I'm seeing that even if my `recv()` call uses a 5 byte buffer and imposes a limit of 5 bytes, I can still send more than 5 bytes and it seems to just queue *somewhere* on the server side, such that the next time `recv()` is called (in a loop for instance), it receives the next 5 bytes of incoming data.

My understanding was that `send()` would fire off its data (lets say all 12 bytes), but since `recv()` is only "set up" to handle 5 bytes, the final 7 would be lost. Where is it that the server is getting these from? Is there an underlying input buffer at the socket level that `recv()` is poping data from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of the socket (within the kernel) handles this automatically for you.

As long as it is a TCP socket you would not lose data. If it is a UDP socket you might lose data if your buffers overflow..

Comment: I figured it would be something similar to this (an underlying buffer mechanism). If its a TCP socket, surely there is some upper bound on the amount of data that can be reliably buffered on the receivers side (unbeknownst to the program)? or is this an instance where if it can't be stored the TCP protocol handles having the data resent from the client/sender machines outbound socket? Thanks!

Comment: @csjohn Yes, there is a limit to the operating system's buffer size. But, as you surmised, the TCP protocol allows the receiver to ask the sender to re-send data that it couldn't fit into the buffer. Again, the operating system handles this for you transparently, so `recv` will just magically work.

Comment: Yes the TCP socket implementation in the kernel handles the ACKs, and re-transmission for you. Also the operating system will maintain a buffer on both the sender and receiver side. On the sender side, if the buffer is full, the `send` would block until the receiver acknowledges receipt of the packets that it could free up from its buffer. On the receiver side, until the application invokes `recv` the receive buffer is not purged.

Comment: @amalloy No. The TCP protocol doesn't permit the sender to even send data that wouldn't fit into the receiver's receive buffer, let alone let the receiver ask the sender to retransmit.

Comment: @EJP Nonsense. TCP tries to avoid sending when the buffer is full, but window-adjustment packets and data packets could pass like ships in the night, allowing packets that won't fit to arrive. And resending data that could not be handled is the core of TCP: if a node receives packet #505 and has not gotten #504, it will ACK 503 to request a retransmission of 504.

Comment: @amalloy I don't see how that is possible. The sender knows how much room there is in the receiver's receiver buffer, as advertised by the receive window, so it can send that much; it will then know that the buffer is full, or reduced by the send size if it was < the window. The sender's idea of the receive window then gets adjusted upwards again by the next window advertisement..

Comment: @EJP Any packet can get lost or delayed, including the ones the receiver sends to advertise its window size.